# Does google read dynamically modified <title> tags?

Tags: php, javascript, seo

My app is built in a fashion similar to Facebook in that it uses a form of pagelets which are generated asynchronously and then sent to the page and injected via javascipt.

This means that I have to set to pages title via javascript also.  My small understanding of SEO lads me to believe that the  tag is extremely important and defines not only what google displays as the title in search results but it will also play a huge part in defining your rankings.

Therefore, my question is:

Does google read, process and taking into account dynamically inserted title tags?

Thanks

Comment: Definitely not a SO question.

Comment: My apologies, I had no idea this would not be appropriate.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the question. In any case, see my answer.

Comment: It should be posted on `webmasters`

Comment: Ahhh, Thanks John, I didn't even realize that existed.  I shall know for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does, if you use the hashbang (#!) to show that it's scrape-able AND you generate the data for Googl to scrape properly, such as with a headless browser, see more:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Comment: Thanks Evan, this answers my question perfectly.  I'll accept as soon as I am able.

Comment: no problem - happy developing!

Comment: You are wrong saying that it does _read, process and taking into account **dynamically** inserted title tags_, because actually google will take everything after #! and put it into specail query parameter and server must return whole page HTML like it is shown after ajax request in browsers. And correct title must be set on server.

Comment: If you execute the javascript and capture the content as described in the link, then yes, in fact, it does. The pedantry is not necessary, thanks.